# Sum the first dimension of a 3D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following 3D `numpy.array` of shape (2,3,3):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(((((1,2,3),(9,8,7),(6,5,4))),
                (((10,20,30),(90,80,70),(60,50,40)))))
```

I want to sum the first dimension and get one 2D array of shape (3,3).

Expected output:

```
array([[11, 22, 33],
       [99, 88, 77],
       [66, 55, 44]])
```

I know I can iterate over the elements in the first dimension and sum, with something like this:

```
for el in range(len(arr)):
    if el == 0:
        arr_sum = arr[el]
    else:
        arr_sum += arr[el]
```

But there is another option to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use `arr.sum(0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use, [NumPy.sum](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) method.

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(((((1,2,3),(9,8,7),(6,5,4))),(((10,20,30),(90,80,70),(60,50,40)))))

print(np.sum(arr, axis=0))
```